# Threading on Mac OS X, force multiple CPUs

Tags: c, multithreading, macos

I have just adding threading to a large application I have been developing for years. It is written in C and runs on Mac and Linux.  This question is about OS X, 10.8.2 or 10.6.8.

Problem:  I see the program opening two threads as I expect.  However, apparently both threads are running on the same CPU, or at least, I never get more than 100% of a CPU allocated to the program.  This almost defeats the entire purpose of having threads.

I use a fair number of mutexes, if that matters.

How can I force the OS to run each thread at 100% of different CPUs?  (There are 8 CPUs on  this machine.)

Comment: Maybe your threads simply doesn't do anything that will cause a big load? Maybe you're sleeping or waiting on other events too much (too heavy use of mutexes might be an indication that a threaded design simply isn't the best one)?

Comment: Your goals are flawed.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg:  Thanks for answering.  Both threads do a great deal of work. There is no sleeping.  My sense is that the percentage of time waiting for the mutexes is very small.

Comment: Jonathan Reinhart:  please explain what is flawed.

Answer (score 3):

The mutexes may matter a lot here. Open up Instruments and run the time profiler instrument on your program *after setting it to "record all thread states"*. This will let you see where your threads are blocked waiting for something (likely a mutex) instead of running.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I never heard of "time profiler instrument" or "instruments."  Apparently it is part of Xcode 4; I have 3.2.6.

Comment: 3.2.6 should have it too. Just open Instruments and look. It's the *primary* performance tool on the platform, you'll need to learn it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple running threads will be concurrent **as long as they execute on different cores** - as each core has it's own instance of the scheduler in every  Unix-like OS. **Being on separate CPU dies matters little**: if fact, there's a benefit to sharing resources between threads running on separate cores of the same die.

Comment: Thanks for responding, however I don't understand what you mean.  Is this a typo: "Being on separate CPU dies matters little"?  I assume you mean "separate CPU matters little"  because the threads will be on different cores.  But I seem to be getting both threads running alternately on the same processor, no parallelism.

Comment: @rfermat A CPU die is the physical silicon. The die may have one or more cores, and the cores on the same die typically share higher levels of cache. We use specific terms like 'core' and 'die' to avoid confusion, as different tools have different means for 'processor' and 'CPU'. See also http://superuser.com/questions/324284/what-is-meant-by-the-terms-cpu-core-die-and-package